# Null reference when trying to cast listbox.selecteditem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

So for a school assignment I have to make an animal shelter,

There are two objects : Cats and Dogs, every new instance of an object is added to an object list  like this:

```
    public Cat Cat { get; private set; }
    public Dog Dog { get; private set; }
    public List<Dog> Dogs = new List<Dog>();
    public List<Cat> Cats = new List<Cat>();

    public void NewCat(string name, Gender gender, string badHabits)
    {
        this.Cat = new Cat(name, gender, badHabits);
        Cats.Add(this.Cat);

    }

    public void NewDog(string name, Gender gender)
    {
        this.Dog = new Dog(name, gender);
        Dogs.Add(this.Dog);
    }
```

with an update method both lists are added to a listbox like this:

```
  private void Update()
    {
            lbAnimals.Items.Clear();
            lbAnimals.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Cat c in reservations.Cats)
        {
            lbAnimals.Items.Add(c.ToString());
        }
        foreach (Dog d in reservations.Dogs)
        {
            lbAnimals.Items.Add(d.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And finally I need to cast the selected object in a listbox to a Dog object or a cat object, this is how it is done for a dog:

```
 private void btnReserveDog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.reservations.Dog != null)
        { 
            var d=  lbAnimals.SelectedItem as Dog; 
                d.Reserve(txtReservor.Text); 
                this.btnReserveDog.Enabled = false;
            Update();
        }
    }
```

No matter what I seem to try, when I cast the object it returns a null reference and I have no idea why, Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: because you are adding string in listbox as elements not Dog

Comment: Do you maybe have an example how I should add it?

Comment: you will have to create a base class Animal, and then inherit Cat and Dog from it, then Create a ``List<Animal>`` which contains both ``Cat`` and ``Dog`` as ``Animal``, then bind that list with lbAnimals like ``lbAnimals.DataSource=animals``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items collection of a `ListBox` will accept objects of any type. You are currently converting your objects from `Cat` and `Dog` to `string` before adding, so of course when you use `as` and try to cast the `string` back to `Dog`, it fails. A `Dog` is not a `string`, which means you get `null` as the result (that's what `as` does when the cast fails).

All you should need to do is remove the `.ToString`(). I.e.:

```
private void Update()
{
    lbAnimals.Items.Clear();
    lbAnimals.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Cat c in reservations.Cats)
    {
        lbAnimals.Items.Add(c);
    }
    foreach (Dog d in reservations.Dogs)
    {
        lbAnimals.Items.Add(d);
    }
}
```

Then, when you are dealing with a `Dog` element in the collection, you'll get the `Dog` instance back when using `as`.

Of course, for `Cat` elements, the result will be `null`. It is still up to you to make sure you handle the `null` value (either by not trying to cast to `Dog` when it's a `Cat` and vice a versa, or by checking for the `null` result).

Comment: This turned out to be the solution for me ! Felt kind of stupid when I found out this was what I spent my entire sunday on to be honest

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display objects in a listbox is not to convert to a string and back but rather since the object has a string property then this should be displayed in the listbox. So try using the DisplayMember property of the listbox instead. So try this

```
LbAnimals.DisplayMember = "name"; // this sets tge property of the object that would be displayed to name.

private void Update()
{
        lbAnimals.Items.Clear();
        lbAnimals.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Cat c in reservations.Cats)
    {
        lbAnimals.Items.Add(c);
    }
    foreach (Dog d in reservations.Dogs)
    {
        lbAnimals.Items.Add(d);
    }
} 

        private void btnReserveDog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           { 
              if (this.reservations.Dog != null)
            { 
                //you also missed a null check here, this might raise an exception if no item is selected in the listbox
           If ( lbAnimals.SelectedItem !=null)
               {
                 Dog  d=  lbAnimals.SelectedItem as Dog; 
                d.Reserve(txtReservor.Text); 
                this.btnReserveDog.Enabled = false;
                Update();
               }
           }
        }
```

Another problem is that you are adding do both Dog and Cat objects to thesame listbox, so when you seldct a cat and try to cast it to a dog, you would also get a null reference exception.  So you might wan to check the type using GetType() method before casting.